# Citing, Secondary Source

Tags: plagiarism

My question is about citing. I found two sectences that were cited in a review article (first sentence[1], extra information about it[2]. Second sentence [3]). And after that i found the original references and read them. (I didn't need ref [2], i just remove it and didn't talk about it)

At the end, i changed the places of them (flipped...1-3 to 3-1). Also i paraphrase them and added some words on them. Because in review article some parts of them were missing. But i gave reference to the original sources not to review article. So, is it considered to be plagiarism in introduction part?

Note: The primary sources are not previous studies on my local research area. They are like descriptions on that field. One of them is reasons of illness and the other one is statistical numbers of sport. Actually i gave the statistical number a bit different like "more than 150 m" instead of "180 m" and I was specific like "who are older than 20 years old". And also for reasons of illness, i gave different reference for ref1 but ref3 kept constant. To be specific; reasons of illness can be described by a doctor easly.

Here, total number of sentences is two.

For example in following link; we see that APA style says that we need to give original reference.

https://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/cite-another-source murdoch university; https://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/APA/secondary apa style blog; https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/05/secondary-sources-aka-how-to-cite-a-source-you-found-in-another-source.html

So what about my question's answer? I just obeyed to rule of APA and after i finished my thesis, i learnt that my situation might be considered as plagiarism for 2 citationss? and my M.Sc. degree can be revoked later?

Comment: Check out all the answers on that question; rarely are questions absolutely perfect duplicates, and there's nothing wrong with your question being a duplicate, it's just that it's already been answered here.

Comment: From where did you learn that your degree could be revoked?  Was this from an official pr professor at your school, or is it a somewhat vague worry?  (If I've read your question correctly, I believe you're safe.  You read everything you cited and cited everything you used.)

Comment: Please do not deface your question just because they have been closed. In particular questions closed as a duplicate still hold some value as they can point others in the right direction.